# PNG resize bug in CollectionFS/GraphicsMagick?

Tags: meteor, graphicsmagick

I’m using CollectionFS and GraphicsMagick and resizing PNGs result in corrupted files (zero KB). JPGs and GIFs work fine.

```
transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    // Transform the image into a 64x64px thumbnail
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('64', '64').stream().pipe(writeStream);
}
```

Any idea if this is a bug or am I missing something? Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, you should search for problem somewhere else in code, since I got same transformWrite and it works with PNGs

Comment: The project: https://github.com/c6y/eboydb. If anyone has the time to have a quick look I'd be really thankful. thumbnails in "/lib/collection.js" converts to jpg at the moment, but it does not matter. I always get corrupted thumbnail files – if PNGs are uploaded.